# CSS ?ver=4.6.1 not updating

Tags: css

I've modified my css via wp editor. I see my modifications when i look for `www.mysite.com/style.css` but the theme is loading `www.mysite.com/style.css?ver=4.6.1` and this version is the old one.

How to force the modifications go live?

Answer (score 4):

The version number `?ver=4.6.1` is coming from the theme's call to the [`wp_enqueue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) function. When the `$ver` parameter is set to `false`, the WordPress version is used for the `ver` query variable.

Making changes to your theme's `style.css` file will not cause browsers to reload the new version of the file. To do that, you'd need to change the `$ver` parameter used in `wp_enqueue_style()` for your theme's stylesheet. Alternatively, you can use a plugin such as [Busted!](https://wordpress.org/plugins/busted/) to do this.

Also, [child themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) are the best way to customize your theme because editing the parent theme directly will result in your customizations to be lost when the theme is updated.

Answer (score 1):

The `ver=4.6.1` that you are seeing is the current WordPress version, which is apparently appended to the css entrance by your theme. It doesn't load a separate file. Your edited `style.css` is live and loaded. If you don't see its effects on your site, empty your browser's cache.